# Why the data disappeared after 'join' operation of dataframe in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two spark dataframe and i can find the row "cp_uin = '709155161 " in both.
but why i find nothing after the join operation? that's really weird and driving me crazy ...

```
cplevel_df.filter("cp_uin_l= '709155161' ").show()
```

> 

```
+---------+------------+---------+             
| cp_uin_l|manual_level|     name|   
+---------+------------+---------+      
|709155161|           4|    namex|     
+---------+------------+---------+     


df_join.where("sim_cp= '709155161' ").show()

+----------+---------+------------+    
|    cp_uin|   sim_cp|sim_cp_score|    
+----------+---------+------------+       
|1028885445|709155161|      0.1510|    
+----------+---------+------------+         

df_join.join(cplevel_df , df_join.sim_cp == cplevel_df.cp_uin_l, "inner").show()       

+------+------+-----------+--------+------------+-----+        
|cp_uin|sim_cp|sim_cp_score|cp_uin_l|manual_level|name|     
+------+------+-----------+--------+------------+-----+        
+------+------+-----------+--------+------------+-----+
```

Both dataframe "cplevel_df " and  "df_join" have lines contains the same key '709155161', so I think there should be the joined line after join operation
by those keys.

Comment: In the first two images, you have shared, in both the field name is cp_uin_l, so check is it the field name issue?

Comment: i'm sorry. i put a wrong image. thanks for reminding

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Put everything needed to ask your question in your post. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Ask about the 1st expression with unexpected result. [ask]

Comment: Please look at the formatted version of your post before posting. Read the edit help re code blocks. PS Cut & paste & run. Etc.

Comment: thank you . This is my first question and  I‘m still learning how to operate it

Comment: Why would there be rows in the result? Explain why you expect what you expect in terms of operator definitions or we can't address your misconceptions & can only say, because that's how the operators are defined, and you don't need us to, nor should you ask us to, write yet another presentation of them. PS For an R or SQL [mre] give input as code formatted as a table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't konw the reason. But when i drop the column named 'cp_uin_l' in dataframe 'df_join' ,my problem was fixed.